# Ebib: edit completion fields

Tags: emacs, bibtex

I am trying to change `ebib--field-edit-functions` in Ebib to add *address* to its fields with completions. The manual says that you need to customize the user option `ebib--field-edit-functions` (actually, it says `ebib-edit-fields-functions` which is likely a typo), but I can't find it. Nor can I do it manually in the init file. The option is set in `ebib-utils.el`. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Question double-posted on a related stackexchange: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78022/ebib-edit-completions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `Elisp` functions with the `--` (double hyphen) in their names are for internal calls only. This is stated in [Coding Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html) [or `(info "(elisp) Coding Conventions")`] and [Tips for Defining](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Tips-for-Defining.html) [or `(info "(elisp) Tips for Defining")`].

Make sure to have the latest version of `ebib` package installed. The function `ebib-field-edit-functions` was added [in Version 2.39](http://joostkremers.github.io/ebib/NEWS.html), hence the manual is not wrong.

[It [was preceded](https://github.com/joostkremers/ebib/commit/4605144c0c2be1fd9bd9af7eff455d900d00da6e) by the now obsolete function `ebib-fields-with-completion`, so you might have this `defcustom` available with an older version of `ebib`.]